# Error in Query (1066): Not unique table/alias: 'useraccounts'

Tags: mysql, qsqlquery

I want to get email and password from user table Where Email is primary key and against email i want balance and AccountID from useraccounts where account id is foreign key. and against that foreign key i want accountNo from table accounts

```
SELECT `user`.`email`, `user`.`passwrd`, `useraccounts`.`Balance`, `useraccounts`.`AccountID`, `accounts`.`AccountNo`
FROM `user` , `accounts`
LEFT JOIN `useraccounts` ON `user`.`email` = `useraccounts`.`email` 
LEFT JOIN `useraccounts` ON `accounts`.`AccountID` = `useraccounts`.`AccountID` 

SELECT `user`.`email`, `user`.`passwrd`, `useraccounts`.`Balance`, `useraccounts`.`AccountID`, `accounts`.`AccountNo`
FROM `user` , `accounts`
LEFT JOIN `useraccounts` ON `user`.`email` = `useraccounts`.`email` 
LEFT JOIN `useraccounts` ON `accounts`.`AccountID` = `useraccounts`.`AccountID`
```

Error is #1066- Not Unique Table/Alias : `useraccounts`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eINX7.jpg)

Comment: Well that's true - you are left joining useraccounts twice you should alias them both (and the columns in the select)

Comment: Once you fix the current error you may hit this issue - 'If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: can u correct this query plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'can u correct this query plz' - perhaps this

```
SELECT `user`.`email`, `user`.`passwrd`, `useraccounts`.`Balance`, `useraccounts`.`AccountID`, `accounts`.`AccountNo`
FROM `user` 
LEFT JOIN `useraccounts` ON `user`.`email` = `useraccounts`.`email` 
LEFT JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`AccountID` = `useraccounts`.`AccountID`
```